# Mostar Texto y Ocultar texto

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este javascript y funciona bien en mostrar y ocultar pero quiero que solo muestre el que se selecciona pero se muestra en todos los divs que puedo hacer para componer eso? Soy super nuevo... es esto..

```
<script>
    alert ("Sitió Web En Desarrollo")
    function info() {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("info-mas");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
            x[i].style.display = "block"; 
        }
    }
    function ocultarinfo() {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("info-mas");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
            x[i].style.display = "none"; 
        }
    }
</script>

<button type="button" class="mas-info" onclick="info()" >Mas Info +</button>
<div class="info-mas">
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p>
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="ocultarinfo()">Menos Info -</a>
</div>
<button type="button" class="mas-info" onclick="info()" >Mas Info +</button>
<div class="info-mas">
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p>
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="ocultarinfo()">Menos Info -</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en tu función usas `getElementsByClassName` para encontrar el elemento que quieres mostrar/ocultar. Pero hay más de un elemento con la misma clase.

Lo que necesitas hacer es diferenciar de alguna forma los elementos a mostrar/ocultar.

A tu código le hice los siguientes cambios:

- Agrego el atributo `data-id` a los elementos que se muestran y ocultan.
- Agrego el parámetro `id` a las funciones `info` y `ocultarinfo`.
- Reemplazo el método `getElementsByClassName` por `querySelectorAll` para hacer una búsqueda más precisa de los elementos (por clase y valor del atributo data-id).

Quedando así:

```js
function info(id) {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll('.info-mas[data-id="' + id + '"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        x[i].style.display = "block"; 
    }
}
function ocultarinfo(id) {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll('.info-mas[data-id="' + id + '"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="mas-info" onclick="info('1')" >Mas Info +</button>
<div class="info-mas" data-id="1">
    <p align="center">texto</p> 
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p>
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="ocultarinfo('1')">Menos Info -</a>
</div>
<button type="button" class="mas-info" onclick="info('2')" >Mas Info +</button>
<div class="info-mas" data-id="2">
    <p align="center">texto</p> 
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p>
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="ocultarinfo('2')">Menos Info -</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto justo lo que necesitaba muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function info(estado) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("info-mas");
        switch(estado){
            case 'menos':
                x[0].style.display = "none"; 
            break;
            case 'mas':
               x[0].style.display = "block"; 
            break;
        }

    }
</script>

<button type="button" class="mas-button" onclick="info('mas')" >Mas Info + 
</button>
<div class="info-mas" style="display:block;">
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p>
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p> 
    <p align="center">  </p>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="info('menos')">Menos Info -</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, explica lo que has hecho y porque , mira mas información mira en [answer] y [tour]